# GraphViz - Create Cluster of Clusters in multiple lines

Tags: graph, graphviz

I would really appreciate your help with regards to the a graph I would like. I want from a starting cluster to have labels to many other clusters, which in turn should be organized in multiple lines.

Until this moment I have written the following code:

```
digraph g{
rankdir="TB";
compound=true;

subgraph cluster0{
label="Cluster 0";
a0->b0;
b0->c0;
a0->c0;
}

subgraph cluster1{
label="Cluster 1";
a1->b1;
b1->c1;
a1->c1;
}

subgraph cluster2{
label="Cluster 2";
a2->b2;
b2->c2;
a2->c2;
}


subgraph cluster3{
label="Cluster 3";
a3->b3;
b3->c3;
a3->c3;
}

subgraph cluster4{
label="Cluster 4";
a4->b4;
b4->c4;
a4->c4;
}

a0->a1 [ltail=cluster0,lhead=cluster1];
a0->a2 [ltail=cluster0,lhead=cluster2];
a0->a3 [ltail=cluster0,lhead=cluster3];
a0->a4 [ltail=cluster0,lhead=cluster4];

}
```

Although this code produces my clusters and appropriately interconnects them, unfortunately all the clusters (i.e. clusters 1,2,3 and 4) are in the same row, whereas I would like clusters 1 and 2 to be in one row and clusters 3 and 4 to be at another row, exactly below the row containing the clusters 1 and 2.

By using invisible links although the clusters are organized together, they are not aligned properly (in columns) and moreover the internal nodes sequence seems to tangle (see for example the following slightly more complicated case where I would like the node labeled 4 to be always on top where the remaining nodes 1,2 and 3 should be placed in the corresponding order from left to right)

```
digraph g {
compound=true;
fontname=Helvetica
page="8.5,11";
size="135";
overlap=false;

subgraph cluster0 {
"start-0" [ label = "4" ];
"n1-0" [ label = "1" ];
"start-0" -> "n1-0" ;
"n2-0" [ label = "2" ];
"start-0" -> "n2-0" ;
"n3-0" [ label = "3" ];
"start-0" -> "n3-0" ;
subgraph 00 { rank = same;  "n1-0" "n2-0" "n3-0" }
}
subgraph cluster1 {
"start-1" [ label = "4" ];
"n1-1" [ label = "1" ];
"start-1" -> "n1-1" ;
"n2-1" [ label = "2" ];
"start-1" -> "n2-1" ;
"n3-1" [ label = "3" ];
"start-1" -> "n3-1" ;
subgraph 01 { rank = same;  "n1-1" "n2-1" "n3-1" }
}
"start-0" -> "start-1" [ltail=cluster0,lhead=cluster1];
subgraph cluster2 {
"start-2" [ label = "4" ];
"n1-2" [ label = "1" ];
"start-2" -> "n1-2" ;
"n2-2" [ label = "2" ];
"start-2" -> "n2-2" ;
"n3-2" [ label = "3" ];
"start-2" -> "n3-2" ;
subgraph 02 { rank = same;  "n1-2" "n2-2" "n3-2" }
}
"start-0" -> "start-2" [ltail=cluster0,lhead=cluster2];
subgraph cluster3 {
"start-3" [ label = "4" ];
"n1-3" [ label = "1" ];
"start-3" -> "n1-3" ;
"n2-3" [ label = "2" ];
"start-3" -> "n2-3" ;
"n3-3" [ label = "3" ];
"start-3" -> "n3-3" ;
subgraph 03 { rank = same;  "n1-3" "n2-3" "n3-3" }
}
"start-0" -> "start-3" [ltail=cluster0,lhead=cluster3];
subgraph cluster4 {
"start-4" [ label = "4" ];
"n1-4" [ label = "1" ];
"start-4" -> "n1-4" ;
"n2-4" [ label = "2" ];
"start-4" -> "n2-4" ;
"n3-4" [ label = "3" ];
"start-4" -> "n3-4" ;
subgraph 04 { rank = same;  "n1-4" "n2-4" "n3-4" }
}
"start-0" -> "start-4" [ltail=cluster0,lhead=cluster4];
subgraph cluster5 {
"start-5" [ label = "4" ];
"n1-5" [ label = "1" ];
"start-5" -> "n1-5" ;
"n2-5" [ label = "2" ];
"start-5" -> "n2-5" ;
"n3-5" [ label = "3" ];
"start-5" -> "n3-5" ;
subgraph 05 { rank = same;  "n1-5" "n2-5" "n3-5" }
}
"start-0" -> "start-5" [ltail=cluster0,lhead=cluster5];

subgraph cluster6 {
"start-6" [ label = "4" ];
"n1-6" [ label = "1" ];
"start-6" -> "n1-6" ;
"n2-6" [ label = "2" ];
"start-6" -> "n2-6" ;
"n3-6" [ label = "3" ];
"start-6" -> "n3-6" ;
subgraph 06 { rank = same;  "n1-6" "n2-6" "n3-6" }
}
"start-0" -> "start-6" [ltail=cluster0,lhead=cluster6];
subgraph cluster7 {
"start-7" [ label = "4" ];
"n1-7" [ label = "1" ];
"start-7" -> "n1-7" ;
"n2-7" [ label = "2" ];
"start-7" -> "n2-7" ;
"n3-7" [ label = "3" ];
"start-7" -> "n3-7" ;
subgraph 07 { rank = same;  "n1-7" "n2-7" "n3-7" }
}
"start-0" -> "start-7" [ltail=cluster0,lhead=cluster7];
subgraph cluster8 {
"start-8" [ label = "4" ];
"n1-8" [ label = "1" ];
"start-8" -> "n1-8" ;
"n2-8" [ label = "2" ];
"start-8" -> "n2-8" ;
"n3-8" [ label = "3" ];
"start-8" -> "n3-8" ;
subgraph 08 { rank = same;  "n1-8" "n2-8" "n3-8" }
}
"start-0" -> "start-8" [ltail=cluster0,lhead=cluster8];
subgraph cluster9 {
"start-9" [ label = "4" ];
"n1-9" [ label = "1" ];
"start-9" -> "n1-9" ;
"n2-9" [ label = "2" ];
"start-9" -> "n2-9" ;
"n3-9" [ label = "3" ];
"start-9" -> "n3-9" ;
subgraph 09 { rank = same;  "n1-9" "n2-9" "n3-9" }
}
"start-0" -> "start-9" [ltail=cluster0,lhead=cluster9];
subgraph cluster10 {
"start-10" [ label = "4" ];
"n1-10" [ label = "1" ];
"start-10" -> "n1-10" ;
"n2-10" [ label = "2" ];
"start-10" -> "n2-10" ;
"n3-10" [ label = "3" ];
"start-10" -> "n3-10" ;
subgraph 010 { rank = same;  "n1-10" "n2-10" "n3-10" }
}
"start-0" -> "start-10" [ltail=cluster0,lhead=cluster10];

"n1-0" -> "start-1" [style=invis];
"n1-0" -> "start-2" [style=invis];
"n1-0" -> "start-3" [style=invis];
"n1-0" -> "start-4" [style=invis];
"n1-0" -> "start-5" [style=invis];

"n3-1" -> "start-6" [style=invis];
"n3-2" -> "start-7" [style=invis];
"n3-3" -> "start-8" [style=invis];
"n3-4" -> "start-9" [style=invis];
"n3-5" -> "start-10" [style=invis];

}
```

Is there any way I could achieve that using dot?

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could try by adding some **invisible edges**:

```
c0->a1 [style=invis];
c0->a2 [style=invis];
c1->a3 [style=invis];
c2->a4 [style=invis];
```

and go from there to improve further if needed.

This makes sure that clusters are positioned on different ranks.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind reply. Please see the edit of my post, in case you could provide me with further assistance.